# p-calendar unable to patch time value through formControlName

Tags: angular, primeng

Currently, I'm working on p-calendar while using p-calender for recording time, which I'm able to get the user selected time. I'm currently facing a problem in assigning the time, Example I need to set a default time which is not happening using formControlName.

HTML:

```
<p-calendar id="calenderid" showTime="true" [timeOnly]="true" placeholder="{{'Select' | translate}}"></p-calendar>
```

When I use

HTML:

```
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [name]="calendar" placeholder="Date" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [formControlName]="calendarPick"></p-calendar>
```

I'm able to set the date value via form control but then, when I use it with time HTML I'm not able to set the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is happening in your code without knowing the content of your component and the full HTML template.

Considering that you are on the latest Angular/PrimeNG, setting the time works as expected for `p-calendar`.

For example with the following form containing a `p-calendar` form control:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="p-3 bg-faded">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Calendar</strong></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <p-calendar formControlName="date"  showTime="true"></p-calendar>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<button (click)="setTime()">Set time to now</button>

<pre>{{ this.form.get("date").value | json }}</pre>
```

With the following component:

```
form: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    date: [new Date()]
  });
}

setTime() {
  this.form.patchValue({
    date: new Date()
  });
}
```

Clicking on the button will set the calendar time to the current time by patching the form control value.